# Removal of responsibility

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What's a better way of saying "removes responsibility"?

> Hard determinism's ______ of responsibility is a fundamental problem for society, as our current punishment systems rely upon individuals having moral choice and culpability.
>
> This ______ of responsibility carries worrying implications

I thought already of "alleviation", "assuagement" but I know that there's a far better alternative that's almost specifically for responsibility, but I can't seem to recall it.

---

Hard determinism is a philosophical branch which states that everyone's actions are *caused* by prior events outside of their control.

Therefore, no one ever makes a truly "free" choice, and ultimately someone's actions can be predicted if one were to know all prior causes.

This removes responsibility from the individual.

Comment: You might ask in the philosophy site. http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Josh maybe, but I've been ruthlessly attacked for crossposting before, and I feel like this should also be on-topic here, as it isn't necessarily philosophy

Comment: I am not sure it is 100% ELU either.

Comment: @Josh why isn't it?

Comment: I think it relies  on the specific knowledge of the HD philosophy, and it is not  clear what you are actually looking for.

Comment: @Josh no, the word actually has nothing to do with philosophy, it doesn't _need_ to be used in a philosophical context, I'm just writing a philosophy essay right now, need the word and so gave these examples. Perhaps I could add more non-philosophy examples.

Comment: If you're looking for something lively and suggestive, "obliteration of" or "absolution from" might work. If you're looking for something a bit more businesslike, "denial of" might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[*Abnegation*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abnegation), perhaps?

> **abnegation** noun
>
> 1. [mass noun] The action of renouncing or rejecting something:
>
>    - abnegation of political power

Oxford Dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ***renunciation***.

> Hard determinism's ***renunciation*** of responsibility is a fundamental problem
>   for society, as our current punishment systems rely upon individuals
>   having moral choice and culpability.
>
> This ***renunciation*** of responsibility carries worrying implications.

ODO:

> **[renunciation](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/renunciation)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** [mass noun] The formal rejection of something, typically a belief, claim, or course of action:
>   ‘the life of the Spirit required
>   renunciation of marriage’
>   [count noun] ‘a renunciation of violence’

Answer (score 0):

This isn't precisely the definition you gave, but in practice, the following phrase is used for what you described:

***[denial](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/denial) of responsibility***

1. an assertion that an allegation is false.
2. refusal to believe a doctrine.
3. disbelief in the existence or reality of a thing.
4. the refusal to satisfy a claim, request, etc., or the refusal of a person making it.
5. refusal to recognize or acknowledge: Peter's denial of Christ.
6. Law. a plea that denies the alleged facts of an adversary's plea.
7. self-denial.
8. Psychol. the reduction of anxiety by the unconscious exclusion from the mind of intolerable thoughts, feelings, or facts: who are alcoholics in denial.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/denial

And the verb: So-and-so denies any responsibility whatsoever.

Comment: I almost downvoted this, but it looks like the conversation in the comments of the OP has been deleted. "Denial" won't work for me as it is like hard determinism actively tries to remove responsibility, which it can't, it's just that its implications are that it seems to remove responsibility from the individual.

Comment: erasure, abolition, elimination, eradication, dismissal, negation, desertion, retreat (from), dismissal (of), departure (from), disintegration (of)....